# How do i remove a like from a photo in my code

Tags: java, oop, testing

I have written a program for a photo upload site where users can like photos, I have a test script to like the photo then display all the likes then i want to remove the like and display all the likes now. How do i do this?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Likes {
    private static Hashtable<Photo, TreeSet<User>> likes = new Hashtable<>();

    //like photo
    public static void like(Photo photo, User user) {
        try {
            likes.get(photo).add(user);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            likes.put(photo, new TreeSet<>());
            likes.get(photo).add(user);
        }
    }



    //unlike photo
    public static void unlike(Photo photo, User user) {
        try {
            likes.get(photo.remove(user));
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }
    }

    //has liked photo
    public boolean hasliked(Photo photo, User user) {
        try {
            return likes.get(photo).contains(user);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //get all likes
    public List<Photo> getAllLikes(User user){
        // new empty list
        List<Photo> likedphotos = new ArrayList<Photo>();

        for (Photo photo : likes.keySet()) {
            if(hasliked(photo, user)){
                // add photo to list
                likedphotos.add(photo);
            }
            // return that initial list
        }

        return likedphotos;

    }



    public String toString() {
        return likes.toString();
    }

    public void get(Photo remove) {
    }

    public void remove(Photo photo1, User user1) {
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.util.*;

public class TestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InputValidationException {



        //create 2 photo object
        Photo photo1 = new Photo();
        Photo photo2 = new Photo();

        //create 1 user object
        User user1 = new User();

        //create 1 like object
        Likes likes1 = new Likes();


        //set 2 photos
        photo1.setimageURL("photo of user 2");
        photo2.setimageURL("photo of user 1");

        //print the 2 photos
        System.out.println(photo1.getimageURL());
        System.out.println(photo2.getimageURL());


        //set 1 user
        user1.setUserName("oopnoob");

        //print the username
        System.out.println(user1.getUserName());

        //Like the 2 photos


        Likes.like(photo1, user1);
        Likes.like(photo2, user1);

        //Test the hasliked method to see if user1 has liked both photos - both should return true

        System.out.println("Should be true: " + likes1.hasliked(photo1, user1));
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + likes1.hasliked(photo2, user1));


        //Test the getAllLikes for user1. Should print 2 photos.

        System.out.println("user1 liked: " + likes1.getAllLikes(user1));


//i dont know how to remove the like from the photo

        //Test the unlike feature by unliking photo1

        likes1.unlike(photo1, user1);


        //Test the getAllLikes - should only print one photo

        System.out.println("user1 liked: " + likes1.getAllLikes(user1));







    }

}
```

Comment: I guess the `unlike` method has a bug: instead of `likes.get(photo.remove(user))` you should use `likes.get(photo).remove(user)`.

Comment: Unrelated: use vertical spacing (empty lines) with **intention**. Dont just throw empty lines here and there. Use them to group things that belong together. Dont have 5 empty lines in the middle of your code for no reason at all. Try to make your code look like you *cared* when you write it.

Comment: And yeah: catching exceptions (especially runtime probems such as null pointer exception) to **ignore** them, that is **super bad**. You just shoot yourself in the foot. And instead of figuring why that is, and how to prevent it in the future, you decide to walk on. Really really bad.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this part of your code

```
   //unlike photo
public static void unlike(Photo photo, User user) {
    try {
        likes.get(photo.remove(user));
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {

    }
}
```

It looks like you are removing the photo and not the 'like'

The code should be

```
    //unlike photo
public static void unlike(Photo photo, User user) {
    try {
        likes.get(photo).remove(user);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {

    }
}
```

Note: Catching a NullPointerException in a class is a really bad idea. If you think a value like photo or user can be null, its best to check before you use the value.  It's also not smart to catch an exception and then  ignore it.
Thanks to @Ghostcat for pointing that out to me.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thanks

Comment: @GhostCat I truly understand what you are trying to say but if I go down that route, I'll probably have to refactor the who class..

Comment: Not really: a comment saying "btw: catching NPE and ignoring is terribly bad" ... would do ;-)